# Amazon Airflow (MWAA) - connect database in private VPC in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-vpc, mwaa

[image]

I used cool pre-configured Amazon Managed Apache Airflow.

BUT: I want to connect there with database which is already in my private VPC.

I found an IP of Amazon MWAA instance, and added to white-list of my VPC Route tables, but still, there is no way to connect:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on ...
```

in DAG logs.

To be sure that everything works on the airflow side, I connected to the public mysql database and everything worked properly.

***** ANSWER: enable peering connection between VPC's and enable DNS hosting *****

Comment: Where is the DB located?

Comment: @PriyadarshanMohanty AWS RDS, eu-west-2, same region as Amazon MWAA, just different VPCs

Comment: Is VPC peering enabled?

Comment: @PriyadarshanMohanty no its not, if I wanted to simply access private database I was just simply white-listing IP, so I did it for MWAA too.

Comment: @PriyadarshanMohanty still, even I created Peering Connection in VPC and added to private VPC MWAA CIDR to route tables its not still connecting properly.

Comment: @PriyadarshanMohanty ok, I enabled DNS settings in the peering connection, and works perfectly! thanks for the hint, have a great day!

Comment: @JohnDoe having same issue. I created Peering and activated DNS. Do I need to whitelist and/or do the MWAA CIDR as well?